# msbuild.exe command line with /p:BuildInParallel=true and /m parameters - what is the difference between the different combinations?

Tags: concurrency, msbuild

Posting this after reading https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx. Either this is clear as mud or I am just plain stupid.

I have always run msbuild.exe on the command line with `/m` without any `/p:BuildInParallel=true` and it always spawned the expected number of msbuild nodes (12 on my desktop, 4 on my laptop) and built the solution projects what the respective degree of concurrency (12 or 4 at a time most of the time).

On the other hand, when I called the `MSBuild` task from my targets filed and passed it more than one project (or a solution file), I have always set the `BuildInParallel` property of the MSBuild task. Because this is how you build projects in parallel using the MSBuild task, right?

Note, that this is a property of the `MSBuild` task, not a build property (like `Configuration`) passed in `MSBuild.Properties`.

The article suggests that there is actually a build property under the same name - `BuildInParallel` and that it compliments the `/m` switch, which is complete news to me. I searched all the *.targets files under **c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild** and the only mentioning of it is in the following context:

1. If the property value is nil, set it to `true`
2. Pass its value to the `MSBuild.BuildInParallel` property.
3. Hard coded pass `false` when building Silverlight projects. (We still have these and I can concur - they are always built sequentially :-()

My conclusion - the article is misleading with respect to passing `BuildInParallel` to msbuild.exe, because it is of no significance, unless we pass `false` there. Which is also not needed, just do not pass `/m`.

But there is always a chance I am missing something here, so my question - what do I loose when running `msbuild.exe /m` without `/p:BuildInParallel=true`?

(I think I know the answer - absolutely nothing, but just in case)

Answer (score 1):

> what do I loose when running `msbuild.exe /m` without `/p:BuildInParallel=true` ?

Normally, you lose nothing. Running with with `/p:BuildInParallel=true` only changes the behavior if you manually adjusted your MSBuild project file accordingly as proposed by the article.

Basically, the article suggests defining a new global property called `BuildInParallel` and passing it to selected `MSBuild` tasks to be able to control their built-in `BuildInParallel` property. But the global property could be called any other name as there is no predefined global property, i.e. no built-in support to automatically pick up the value of a certain global property. The only thing built-in is the property `BuildInParallel` of the `MSBuild` task (most/all other tasks don't have this property).

> `BuildInParallel` allows the `MSBuild` task to process the list of projects which were passed to it in a parallel fashion, while /m tells MSBuild how many processes it is allowed to start.

> **More Granularity (if needed)**
>
> If you are custom-crafting your MSBuild files, you could turn off parallelism on just certain MSBuild tasks by adding:
>
> `BuildInParallel=$(BuildInParallel)`
>
> to specific MSBuild Tasks and then just those sub-projects wouldn't build in parallel if you passed in a property from the command line:
>
> `MSBuild /m:4 /p:BuildInParallel=false`
>
> But this an edge case as far as I'm concerned.

Here is an example MSBuild project file to illustrate the use case to build some projects in parallel (if `/m` is passed on the command line), to build some projects in parallel (if `/m` and `/p:BuildInParallel=true` is passed on the command line) and to always build some projects sequentially.

```
<!-- built in parallel if both /m and /p:BuildInParallel=true are specified -->
<MSBuild
    Projects="Solution_with_projects_to_build_in_parallel_1.sln"
    Targets="Build"
    BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)">
</MSBuild>
<!-- built in parallel if /m is specified -->
<MSBuild
    Projects="Solution_with_projects_to_build_in_parallel_2.sln"
    Targets="Build">
</MSBuild>
<MSBuild
    Projects="Solution_with_projects_always_built_sequentially.sln"
    Targets="Build"
    BuildInParallel="false">
</MSBuild>
```